# Euclidian Distances between points

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I have an array of points in numpy:

```
points = rand(dim, n_points)
```

And I want to:

1. Calculate all the l2 norm (euclidian distance) between a certain point and all other points
2. Calculate all pairwise distances.

and preferably all numpy and no for's. How can one do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to use SciPy, the `scipy.spatial.distance` module (the functions `cdist` and/or `pdist`) do exactly what you want, with all the looping done in C. You can do it with broadcasting too but there's some extra memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This might help with the second part:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
p=rand(3,4) # this is column-wise so each vector has length 3
sqrt(sum((p[:,np.newaxis,:]-p[:,:,np.newaxis])**2 ,axis=0) )
```

which gives

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.37355868,  0.64896708,  1.14974483],
   [ 0.37355868,  0.        ,  0.6277216 ,  1.19625254],
   [ 0.64896708,  0.6277216 ,  0.        ,  0.77465192],
   [ 1.14974483,  1.19625254,  0.77465192,  0.        ]])
```

if p was

```
array([[ 0.46193242,  0.11934744,  0.3836483 ,  0.84897951],
   [ 0.19102709,  0.33050367,  0.36382587,  0.96880535],
   [ 0.84963349,  0.79740414,  0.22901247,  0.09652746]])
```

and you can check one of the entries via

```
sqrt(sum ((p[:,0]-p[:,2] )**2 ))
0.64896708223796884
```

The trick is to put newaxis and then do broadcasting.

Good luck!