# Calculating Euclidian distance for multiple image histograms

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so this is the function calculating the histogram:

```
def image_histogram():
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    im = Image.open('/Users/Adnan/Desktop/Archive/0.jpg')
    im_vals1 = np.zeros(256)
    im_vals2 = np.zeros(256)
    im_vals3 = np.zeros(256)

    r,g,b = im.split()

    pixels_r = list(r.getdata())
    pixels_g = list(g.getdata())
    pixels_b = list(b.getdata())
    pix_r = np.array(pixels_r)
    pix_g = np.array(pixels_g)
    pix_b = np.array(pixels_b)
    for idx in range (0, len(pix_r)):
        im_vals1[pix_r[idx]] += 1
        im_vals2[pix_g[idx]] += 1
        im_vals3[pix_b[idx]] += 1
    histogram = list(im_vals1) + list(im_vals2) + list(im_vals3)
    return histogram
print(image_histogram())
def euclidean_distance():
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    a = image_histogram()
    b = image_histogram()
    dist = distance.euclidean(a,b)
print(euclidean_distance())
```

ok so this function now calculates the histogram of 1 image (0.jpg). I would like to know how could i run this same function multiple times with diff images and store each images histogram as a list to then be used by the euclidean distance function. Im guessing some sort of recursion should do the trick but do not know how to go about this since I can not seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: The Euclidean distance between 2 vectors, or do you mean something else? If you do mean this, then have you looked at the formula? On the right of your post, there are also many related questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483100/euclidian-distances-between-points?rq=1) that might help.

Comment: its being used to compare image histograms to find similar images in the folder

Comment: i really just need help creating the function that will use whats above n calculate the Euclidian distance and dont know what to do i have been searching this site but havent come up with anything

Answer (score 4):

From my computer vision course, I remember that one of the best metrics for calculating the distance between two histograms is the chi-squared distance.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184101/comparing-two-histograms-using-chi-square-distance

In python, it can be a custom metric for sklearn Nearest Neighbor function:

```
def chiSquared(p,q):
    return 0.5*np.sum((p-q)**2/(p+q+1e-6))
```

Comment: well sadly were specifically told to use euclidean distance and hamming but thank you

Comment: Well then you can still use KNearestNeighbor.  The default is Euclidian distance.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html